# Why wont my message passing IPC code work? (C)

Tags: c, linux, ipc

I'm trying to write a program to implement basic message passing between a parent and child process. I'm doing this on the linux subsystem for windows 10. I've never used C before, so I've been stumbling my way through and reading tutorials for the past 2 days, but I can't seem to get it to work. The most I can do is create the message queue without errors. 
Here is my code, commented with my best understanding of what I'm doing:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>

//this is the structure of the message i'm sending to the queue
struct message
{
    long messagetype;
    char text[10];
}; 

int main()
{

    key_t key = 2222;
    int msqid = msgget(key, IPC_CREAT); //create a message queue with the key


    pid_t parentpid = getpid();
    pid_t childpid = fork(); //these are mostly unused for now
    if(childpid < 0) //fork failed
    {
        printf("fork failed\n");
        return 1;
    } else if(childpid == 0) //in child process
    {
        struct message sndmsg; //create a message to be send to the queue
        printf("input message\n"); 
        scanf("%s", sndmsg.text);  //get the messages text fro input
        printf("Sending message to queue: %s\n", sndmsg.text); 
        sndmsg.messagetype = 1; //set message type to 1
        if(msgsnd(msqid, &sndmsg, sizeof(sndmsg.text), 0) < 0 ) // no idea what the last parameter really means here. check if message send fails 
        {
            printf("error sending message\n");
        } else
        {
            printf("sent message with text: %s\n",sndmsg.text);
        }

        printf("child process\n");
    } else
    {
        wait(NULL); //wait until child process is done
        struct message rcvmsg; //create a message to recieve the test from the queue
        rcvmsg.messagetype = 1; //matching the message type here
        if(msgrcv(msqid, &rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg.text), 1, 0) < 0) //again, no idea what the last parameter does here. Checking to see if message recieve fails.
        {
            printf("error recieving message\n");
        } else
        {
        printf("recieved message text : %s\n", rcvmsg.text);
        }
        printf("Parent process\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run, I get failures (returned values are < 0) on both message send and recieve. I am completely lost on what IPC_CREATE means, IPC_NOWAIT, etc. Just generally what the last parameter does in msgsnd and msgrcv. In examples, I see people using 0660 | IPC_CREAT, with no explanation of what 0660 is. Can anybody shed some light on what I'm doing wrong in my code, or in general explain message passing in C for someone who usually uses C# and Java cause right now it's basically black magic. Every resource or tutorial I've found so far just goes over my head once it reaches a certain point. Thanks.

Comment: After it fails use perror("msgget"); and perror("msgsnd"); to print the error message

Comment: I get "msgsnd: Function not implemented" and "msgrcv: Function not implemented". I can't find any answers on solving this, I seem to have all the necessary includes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- About `0660 | IPC_CREAT`: The `msgflg` argument of `msgget` is a collection of flags, that is some bits shall be set there. `IPC_CREAT` is one of those bits, and its presence instructs the kernel to create the message queue. Lower 9 bits (in this case `0660`) encode the *permissions* for the queue.

  In this example, `0660` is an octal number, encoding three triplets of bits: `110`, `110` and `000`. Bits in these triplets represent *read*, *write*, and *execute* permissions for the owner of the queue, members of the owner's group, and the rest of the world respectively. In this case, user and the group are allowed to read and write the queue, and the rest have no permissions whatsoever.

  Since you specified no permissions (a plane `IPC_CREAT` and nothing else), your send and receive calls are bound to fail with `Permission denied` error.
- `Function not implemented` is a completely different beast. I don't know much about linux on windows, but I am afraid that for now you are out of luck. See [here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-windows-subsystem-for-l/suggestions/16244947-system-v-ipc-support-needed) and [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1443). Message queues are not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

"Function not implemented" (error code ENOSYS) means your version of Linux has this feature turned off. Not too surprising since it's considered obsolete.

You could rebuild your kernel to enable the feature (likely a pain if you are using a standard kernel) or use a different IPC mechanism such as pipes.